# Paypal ipn processing and dropdown option/price buttons logic

Tags: process, paypal, logic, payment, paypal-ipn

I read lots of post from various sites including paypal documentations. But I have some quesitons wihch I couldnt solve those. One of them is that how to design the codes after receiving the ipn message. Ofcourse I make my code I am able to optain and process the variables of message. like payment status and I am able to save them into database. But the point is that how should I desing the code to control the payment to overcome my requirements. I know the post become long but I feel the need of this explanation. So I have a site which works with membership with payment. Site is check after login the membership trial is expired or not if it is expired it shows a div in fornt of the site wihch includes the paypal buttons and redirect to paypal payment screen when button is clicked. User shodul have ability to choos membership period like 6 or 12 mounths (by dropdown paypal button). When the user finalize his payment ipn is trrigerd and I get the datas but all my members dont have to have a paypal account so they can use therid credit card directli and if I understand correctly the transfer of money can take some time to be recevied by me. Which time interval I should set the members approved flag is true ? I am confused about this. If I approve him after ipn is sent is there a possibility an error can occure while transferring me. How the process works.

other problem is the dropdown button. when I set option/price button when I click the button an error page is shown after redirecting to my selling page. It does not redirect to the payment page.

Realy sorry for my long post but I dont know how can I descirebethe situtation in a short way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to wait until funds are available, you should test the value of "payment_status" in the verified IPN message for "Completed".

An eCheck can take from 3-5 days for collection (sometimes longer; you can see the estimated hold time in your account) and has payment_status="Pending". Once collected, you will get another IPN message with "Completed".

Note that the user never sees the IPN process. Normally you set up the conditions (in a table or something that is persistent enough), then send the user to PayPal. When the user comes back from PayPal, your code (at the "return_url") checks the table to see if Payment had completed successfully (perhaps a flag, which was set by your IPN handler code that is called by/communicated with PayPal when the user leaves PayPal gracefully).

Comment: I have difficulty to understand your post because of lack of my knowledge about both english and paypal coding.

In my notify url I am looking the variables and status of payment and I am releating the payment with member by user id. I am saving the txn_id payment date user id payment amoun currency and mails both payer end receiver. Once the user finalize his payment I am stroing the entri wtih user id but in 3-5 days how to check the pending payment is compleated or not when the user not logged in?... And I think the member doesn want to wait until the payment complete in a week :S

Comment: Again I dont understand what should ı do with return url.
Maybe I should releate the order with email to make it stable? And how long paypal sends the ipn message , when it stops sending it.

Comment: In addition, I am listing the payments in panel of members to show them their payments.

Comment: Well, there are the politics, and the technical...
Politics: Do you want to give the user access when you don't really know if you got paid or not? What if I bought a gold watch with e-check and then 35 hours later, cancel the payment? Did you already ship the watch ("Member doesn't want to wait...")?
Technical: You normally get an IPN message "instantly", but I have seen where there have been outages and no IPN message is sent for hours or 10 minutes (happened 2013-01-28, in fact when their IPN mechanism went down for 15 hours, then they sent all the backed up IPN messages).

Comment: IPN happens on back-end, away from the user.

return_url is a front end (script) that you told PayPal to send the user after payment. It is up to that script to logically connect the back-end operation to what the user sees (and the return url is called "right away" but the IPN may not be so lucky).

Comment: I usually will use the "custom" var to connect the pieces together. Since your ipnurl can be called by anybody, you need to protect yourself (some do this by sending a hash that signs the essential items you are expecting in "custom"; if you're the only one who knows how to sign it, you can be confident that it's hard for somebody to spoof the ipnurl with a valid set of variables - people do try!).
At any rate, my design is that the custom or invoice_number vars are populated, and when IPN comes back, it has those same values, so I update the sales record with the txn_id, payment_status etc.

Comment: Thanx for your reply and patience Jimzie. I understood what you meant about the payment status and notif url I think. I will set the custom var with user id. And I will update with txn_id. But I am still confues about return_url how should I proccess the return_url what can ı do with it... Please forgive my silly questions but this is my first experience with paypal and payment systems.

Comment: I read "IPN is for instant payment notification. It will give you more reliable/useful information than what you'll get from auto-return." this in somewhere and it confueses also. And how can I prepare the bill for the user ?

Comment: should I use pdt to store data If I how to prevent to store the same transaction with both ipn and pdt I think I shoudl use one of them.

Comment: what if I check all the payment_status to be informed about the payment. If ipn shows me the status is reversed or failed couldn I set the member as blocked ? is this usless ?

If I use turkish paypal account can I accept the payment automaticaly if not why? And ı think this is the last there is tow payment type echeck and instant and instand includes credit card what is the diferecen of this with echeck?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23641/discussion-between-jimzie-and-freezer)